# Is this an expression and if so what does it mean?

Tags: translation

I am wrestling my way through an recent article in the yomiyuri shimbun and I came across this sentence:

開催時期は６月から７月初旬を軸に調整する

My question is regarding this part: 軸に調整する

It really does not make sense to me, is it an expression and if so what does it mean?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

> 「(specific time/date) を軸{じく}に調整{ちょうせい}する」

is actually a fairly common phrase used in business, news reporting, etc. meaning:

> "to schedule (something) around (specific time/date)"

It simply means that the specific time/date mentioned is the first choice for those responsible for scheduling the event.

「軸に」 here roughly means "mainly".